# How can i use multiple interceptors for specific request such as POST, Get and PUT?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, request, interceptor

I am using spring boot and cloud in the project. For logging, I am using Interceptors. Since I am new to interceptors I am having difficulty using multiple interceptors. Like can I use a specific interceptor for the specific task? For example, when I request a post, the POST interceptor is called, when I use GET the get interceptor is called. and how can I code for multiple interceptors too?

I never tried anything yet for that because I am not getting the logic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define all HTTP interceptors that you want, every interceptor should implement the logic of intercept an HTTP request.

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class GetRequestInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

        if (request.getMethod().equals(HttpMethod.GET.name())) {
            log.info("intercepting GET request {}", request.getRequestURI());

        }

        return true;
    }
}


@Slf4j
@Component
public class PostRequestInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

        if (request.getMethod().equals(HttpMethod.POST.name())) {
            log.info("intercepting POST request {}", request.getRequestURI());
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

And then you have to register them in spring.

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Configuration
public class WebConfigurer implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private final GetRequestInterceptor getInterceptor;
    private final PostRequestInterceptor postRequestInterceptor;


    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(getInterceptor);
        registry.addInterceptor(postRequestInterceptor);
    }

}
```

Comment: so kind explanation

Answer (score 0):

@earandap

Your comment worked Thanks a lot.
Here is my code:

```
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
        throws Exception {

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    request.setAttribute("startTime", startTime);

    log.info("[START]  [" + request.getMethod() + "] [ URL is: " + request.getRequestURL().toString()
            + " Body is: {}]");

    return true;

}

@Override
public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
        ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {

    long startTime = (long) request.getAttribute("startTime");
    request.removeAttribute("startTime");
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    log.info("[END]  [" + request.getMethod() + "]   [ URL is:" + request.getRequestURL().toString()
            + "]  [Execution Time: {} miliseconds]", (endTime - startTime));
}
```